# Azure Event Hub: What type of data it can ingest

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-stream-analytics

1. Is this true that Azure Stream Analytics can only accept JSON files?
2. Can you possibly ingest/send pipe delimited or other file formats to Event Hub and consume them from Stream Analytics?

Comment: What are you trying to do? You *could* support any format with a custom gaateway (that's how MQTT support was added). ASA would receive the *parsed* data so it doesn't really care about formats

Comment: We need to ingest 1 file per 15 seconds. File format is custom it is neither JSON, nor CSV or Avro. It will require custom parsing. Because of Event Hub scalability we thought Event Hub will be useful for this task. What would you recommend?

Comment: *Scalability* means using minimal parsing. Otherwise EventHub will end up *parsing* instead of *ingesting*. One option is simply to change the format on the client side (how big are the files and how are they created?). Another option is to create a site to act as a gateway and receive the file, convert it then pass it to Event Hub. This has the advantage that you could batch multiple such files up to the 256KB limit.

Comment: Changing the file format on the client side is not an option for us.

Comment: Why not? How large is the file anyway? If it's small enough to send, it's small enough to *change* right before publishing. Remember, you are publishing events, not pushing files

Comment: We do not own client side they are external. At present files are dropped onto our SFTP and we have scripts that parse and load these files into a database. Each file is between 1MB to 4MB. We are considering using Azure but out of the box it seems it supports JSON, CSV and Avro formats.

Comment: Event Hub is about *events*, not ETL. For example, you could just post the file directly to Blob storage without going through Event Hub. You are looking at the wrong service. You can't even publish a file that large to Event Hub. You should look to DataFactory for ETL. Other options are Azure Functions and Web Jobs.

Comment: Azure Functions can be triggered by Blob events, so they can run automatically when you upload a file. You can parse the file in there and if you really need event processing, post individual events to Event Hub and ASA. (Probably need to convert all that to a blog post, sigh)

Comment: Imagine if the files are uploaded to Blob instead of current SFTP server. The file format will be custom. What process in Azure will parse these files?

Comment: Already posted this. Anything that can execute custom code will do. DataFactory is the specialized ETL service. Azure Functions and Web Jobs can run custom code if you don't want the full ETL environment.

Comment: Whoever changed the title yesterday and approved the change: You changed the question *completely*. Besides, ASA *doesn't* use Event Hub "underneath".

Answer (score 1):

Stream Analytics has a drop down menu labeled serialization (in the Manager or old portal at manage.windowsazure.com) that will allow you to choose CSV or Avro as well.

[image: the drop down menu to select data type in event hubs looks like this]

Comment: That dropdown is form Stream Analytics, not Event Hub

Answer (score 0):

What is the file content? Maybe, there is a sense to put a file to the Azure storage and send a link to it to the Event Hub/Service Bus Queue? Or just put files to the storage and consume them with Stream Analytics.